# Ruby Datamapper table inheritance with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper, merb

I started learning [Datamapper](http://datamapper.org/) and what I liked about it was that I can write my models with real inheritance.

Now I wonder, if it is possible to be more advanced about this:

```
class Event
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :begin, DateTime
  property :type, Discriminator
end

class Talk<Event
  property :title, String
  belongs_to :meeting
end

class Meeting<Event
  has n, :talks
end
```

That code fails to create the `:title` column for the `Talk` and obviously, the discriminator column is of little value here, because from a database view, there should be separate tables for both `Talk` and `Meeting`.

So, in the end, I want `Talk` and `Meeting` to share the same properties as defined in `Event` but with possible additional properties and with a 0..1:n relation (A meeting can have several talks but there are talks without a meeting.) Is there a way to accomplish this without either repeating the column definitions and/or abandoning inheritance?

**Edit**

To give another example: The part that I like about the inheritance thing is, that general `Event`s can be queried separately. So, when I want to know, if there is something at a certain `:begin` date, I don’t need to look in two or more tables but could just query the `Event` table. In a way, the following structure could fit my needs.

```
class Event
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :begin, DateTime
end

class Talk
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :meeting
end

class Meeting
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :event
  has n, :talks
end
```

However, in order to use this, I would need to manually create an `Event` every time, I want to create or edit a `Talk`. That is, I can’t do `talk.begin` or `Talk.create(:begin => Time.now)`. Is there a way around this without patching all functions and merging the properties? I don’t want to be reminded of the underlying structure when using the model.

Comment: Which type of inheritance do you mean by real inheritance- Single Table Inheritance, Class Table Inheritance, or Concrete Table Inheritance? http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Comment: I mean Ruby class inheritance.

Comment: Whatever this means table-wise, I don’t care that much about – as long as I can use each Ruby model separately and cast/assign from subclass to parent and back.

Comment: In that case, I think it could be done with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to replicate the attributes of Event into Talk and Meeting then you could move it into a module:

```
module EventFields
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :id, DataMapper::Types::Serial
      property :begin, DateTime 
      # other fields here
    end
  end
end

class Talk
  include EventFields
  property :title, String
  belongs_to :meeting
end

class Meeting
  include EventFields
  has n, :talks
end
```

This will give you different tables but means duplication is reduced.

Comment: But this unfortunately means, there is no transparent way to query all Events at the same time, so I would have to duplicate for all types of events.

Comment: True, but single table inheritance is only reasonably suitable for objects that behave differently but have the same underlying structure/table.

You'll need to take the hit of storing all attributes (for instance in the Event class) and building the logic for the relationships inside each child class.

Unfortunately, STI suggests there is some magic flexible data solution but it's rarely the case. As the models grow apart they'll become too tightly coupled and STI won't make sense any more.

Comment: You are right, I will have to make a compromise anyway for such structures. Hopefully, at some point, DataMapper::EmbeddedValue will be available to ease your suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with 1.2.0: "uninitialized constant DataMapper::Types" - you need to use `DataMapper::Property`