# How to: Single Table Inheritance in DataMapper?

Tags: sinatra, single-table-inheritance, sti, ruby-datamapper, sqlite3-ruby

I'm learning **Sinatra** (1.3.2) and chose to use **DataMapper** (1.2.0) as ORM and an in-memory **SQLite** (1.3.6) DB to start.
Two models, `Books` and `Downloads`, are sharing most attributes, so I looked into declaring a model for STI (**Single Table Inheritance**) in DataMapper. Reading [the docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/misc.html), this seems a piece of cake thanks to [Types::Discriminator](http://rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/Property/Discriminator).

I abstracted all common ones into `DownloadableResource`:

```
class DownloadableResource
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :created_at,   DateTime
  property :modified_at,  DateTime
  property :active,       Boolean,  default: true

  property :position,     Integer

  property :title,        String,   required: true
  property :url,          URI,      required: true
  property :description,  Text,     required: true

  property :type,         Discriminator
end
```

Following [the example](http://datamapper.org/docs/misc.html), I thought it's just as easy as specifying what needs to be extended:

```
class Book < DownloadableResource
  property :cover_url,    URI
  property :authors,      String,   required: true, length: 255
end
```

and

```
class Download < DownloadableResource
  property :icon_url,     URI
end
```

but this was giving me the following error:

> DataObjects::SyntaxError: **duplicate column name: id** (code: 1, sql state: , query: ALTER TABLE "**downloadable_resources**" ADD COLUMN "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, uri: sqlite3::memory:?scheme=sqlite&user=&password=&host=&port=&query=&fragment=&adapter=sqlite3&path=:memory:)

while removing the id generated another (obvious) error:

> DataMapper::IncompleteModelError: DownloadableResource must have a key to be valid

I got around this by adding `include DataMapper::Resource` to both `Book` and `Download`, and then `Book` needed a key to be valid, now looking like this:

```
class Book < DownloadableResource
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial

  property :cover_url,    URI
  property :authors,      String,   required: true, length: 255
end
```

Same goes for `Download`, but now the issue is:

> DataObjects::SyntaxError: **duplicate column name: id** (code: 1, sql state: , query: ALTER TABLE "**books**" ADD COLUMN "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, uri: sqlite3::memory:?scheme=sqlite&user=&password=&host=&port=&query=&fragment=&adapter=sqlite3&path=:memory:)

Starting to feel like I'm going in circles, what's the proper way to implement Single Table Inheritance in DataMapper?

---

PS: I have looked at

- [DataMapper - Single Table Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8858451/341929) and
- [Ruby Datamapper table inheritance with associations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1829161/341929)

but I still have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend this approach:

```
module DownloadableResource

  def self.included base
    base.class_eval do
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :created_at,   DateTime
      property :modified_at,  DateTime
      property :active,       base::Boolean,  default: true

      property :position,     Integer

      property :title,        String,   required: true
      property :url,          base::URI,      required: true
      property :description,  base::Text,     required: true

      property :type,         base::Discriminator
    end
  end
end

class Book
  include DownloadableResource
  property :id, Serial
  # other properties
end

class Download
  include DownloadableResource
  property :id, Serial
  # other properties
end
```

Comment: `NameError: uninitialized constant DownloadableResource::Boolean`

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same. But when I add `property :id, Serial` I get `undefined method \`properties' for DataMapper::Property::Serial:Class`. Any idea?

Comment: I hadn't the problem if I defined the id in the module instead of the class... strange...

Comment: nice idea but this don't work for me cause I use dm-timestamps and this don't work + I need a way to query all Inheritance types at once